# Modeling Conversion Events in a Data Warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

How should I model conversion events?

For instance, if a sales opportunity goes from "stage: prospecting" to "stage: validating", should that be treated as a changing dimension, or a conversion event in the fact table?

Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is commonly represented with an [accumulating snapshot fact table](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/accumulating-snapshot-fact-table/) or [timestamped accumulating snapshot fact table.](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/05/design-tip-145-time-stamping-accumulating-snapshot-fact-tables/) Accumulating snapshot tables model events in progress for business processes that involve a predefined series of steps. The timestamped.

You'll have a date key in the table that represents the date the opportunity hit each stage. If you need to reproduce what pipeline looked like on a given day or track the fact that an opportunity went into and out of a stage multiple times, you might need to consider the timestamped accumulating snapshot.